# Runtime Permissions: Android

Tags: android-permissions

I  ask the permission at the beginning. but if the user disable permission (By going into application > app name > authorize permission > disable) while the application is in "**OnPause**" after given permission, the application get Crash because when app **OnResume**,application has lack of Permission.

How can i resolve this problem?

Comment: ask the permission at onStart();

Comment: I do not want ask permission in all activity, even if i ask in onResume it works, but i have to apply checkPermission in all my activities. i do not want that.

Comment: then thinking about to run service?